# How/where does Express determine content-type for static files

Tags: node.js, express

I have an Express project with the following defined:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

For an url like `/xxx.mp3`, the file `public/xxx.mp3` is served with the `Content-Type` set to `audio/mpeg`. Where or how is this determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express uses Connect, Connect uses Mime, and Mime includes the files mime.types (with default mime types from Apache) and node.types (with some further types contributed by node community). You could just customize one of these files within your copy of mime in node_modules to add your required content type, or Mime also has an API that lets you specify additional content-types or .types files to load from your code.

https://github.com/broofa/node-mime

Comment: Hi vivek, the answer you provided should have a code snippet to explain the answer completely. Please go through some of the answers on StackOverflow, which might help you in future :) Thanks!

Comment: @GaganGupta okay. I will do that, thanks dear for this Suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

**Extend the mime types**

```
express.static.mime.define({'text/plain': ['md']});
```

in Express 4.x

```
    var options = {
      dotfiles: 'ignore',
      etag: false,
      extensions: ['htm', 'html'],
      index: false,
      maxAge: '1d',
      redirect: false,
      setHeaders: function (res, path, stat) {
        res.set('x-timestamp', Date.now())
      }
    }

    app.use(express.static('public', options))
```

Ref: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#setHeaders

Comment: I can't find a `mime` property at https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static. Is it possible to read all the existing mappings?